# using timezones like EST, CET, PST in php

Tags: php, timezone

I want to use timezones which are under the [Others](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php) section in php like EST, PST, CET but there is a warning telling not to.. so what's the alternative if I *do* need them? Is it safe to use them despite the warning?

Comment: You can use the notation: `-0500` and then change it as you need it Or use the exact location e.g. `America/New_York`

Comment: You should really avoid using them.  There are 5 separate meanings of "CST",  and many other ambiguities, [as listed here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations).

Comment: I see.. well I guess I'll go with the solution of @rizier123

Comment: @tamir Should I post an answer ?

Comment: @rizier123 yea I can't seem to find any other solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as mentioned in the comments already with `CST` or `EST`,... it's not clear what exactly you mean, because there are multiple meanings for these as you can see in this [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) here.

So either use the notation: `-0500` or specify your location (e.g. `America/New_York`) with one of the supported timezones which you can see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).